# Angular live development server works on Firefox but not chrome

Tags: angular

I've tried:

- cleaned pacman package cache
- reinstalled nodejs and npm
- deleted ~/.npm

Nothing happened. When I hit localhost:4200 it's like the server is not started, but actually I started the server by ng serve.

I dunno why it only works on Firefox. Is there someone who faced this trouble?

**EDIT**

Idk, it works with

> ng serve --host 0.0.0.0

Something is wrong with my network configuration xD

[See this GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2375)

**EDIT 2**

Actually using this command:

> ng serve --host 127.0.0.1

When I hit localhost:4200, it just worked xD

---

I've changed the script in the package.json to:

> "script": { "start": "ng serve --host 127.0.0.1" }

Comment: try `ng serve --prod` and see if you get any errors or different behavior

Comment: I didn't get any error except "Don't use this for production" warning.

Comment: can you show us your package.json ?

Comment: Sure, https://pastebin.com/fwHTJi9C